How to add custom header when calling to APNS when using AWS SNS?
I want to send time-sensitive notification to iOS, using AWS SNS.
Per Apple's doc, I need to add apns-priority and apns-expiration to the request header. The problem is I am using AWS SNS and I haven't found the correct way to add these headers to the request to AWS SNS.
I found this documentation from AWS, but it has many problems:

It does not have field related to expiration, only priority
I tried to set priority using AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PRIORITY but it is not working

Here's the snippet in TS (using sandbox for now because it's dev environment)
const params = {
  Message: JSON.stringify({
    APNS_SANDBOX: JSON.stringify({
      'apns-expiration': '0',
      'interruption-level': 'time-sensitive',
      aps: {
        alert: {
          body: ' ',
        },
        'mutable-content': 1,
        message: message,
      },
      deepLink: deepLink,
    }),
  }),
  MessageStructure: 'json',
  MessageAttributes: {
    'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PRIORITY': { DataType: 'String', StringValue: '10' },
  },
  TargetArn: device.snsArn,
};

await this.snsClient.send(new PublishCommand(params));

